# NicEdit help needed

Tags: nicedit

Two questions:

1) Do you know if it's possible to create a new button in NicEdit which adds a DIV tag around the selected word, instead of a SAPN tag?

2) I would like to have buttons placed outside the NicEdit area, which calls the appropriate function in NicEdit to add ie.

DIV CLASS="XXX"
TEXT SELECTED
/END DIV

Do you know if one may simply call the appropriate function to add a DIV HTML tag?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1) To add a new button to the nicEditor panel you need to extend the `nicEditorAdvanceButton`, as seen [here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/516/Creating%20a%20Plugin).
The function you will write for this extended button when clicked will wrap your selected text with the html `div` tag.

2) This again is straightforward, you just need to call the function you require of the instance of the panel from where ever your outer button is placed.